# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'queue' of undefined" occured during backbone and signalR integration

Tags: signalr, backbone-views, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a signalR server queue hab. I am trying to start the server and send a messege to the server when a button is clicked in my SearchResultListItemView view. But can not working and I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'queue' ".

This is my SearchResultListItemView view where i have to call the signalR server when the a click event is occured. I just want to sent some value to the server on click. Then I will sent response to all other client to load changes. How can i do this? or what's the problem here??

```
window.SearchResultListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "tr",

initialize: function () {

    var _this = this;
    this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    // here is the error occured in this line:
    var queue = $.connection.queue;

    // Start the connection
    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        queue.ReloadQueueMember("Hello World!", "hi all");
    });
},

events: {
    "click a": "JoinQueue"
},

JoinQueue: function (e) {       
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.model.get("QueueName");
    var Id = this.model.get("CustomerId");

     //SignalR Proxy created on the fly
      queue.send(name, 'hannan19')
      .done(function () {
            console.log('Success!')
       })
       .fail(function (e) {
            console.warn(e);
       });
},

render: function () {
    var data = this.model.toJSON();
    _.extend(data, this.attributes);
    $(this.el).html(this.template(data));
    return this;
}
});
```

And this is my SignalR server:

```
public class Queue : Hub
{
    public void Send(string QueueName, string UserName)
    {
        Clients.ReloadQueueMember(QueueName, UserName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things to check:

- Make sure you're using the latest version off of NuGet (at the moment, 1.0.0-rc1; you'll need to check "include prerelease" to see it).
- If `$.connection` is undefined, make sure you're loading the static SignalR client (at the moment, "jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.js"). Check the "Network" tab of the developer tools of your favorite browser to confirm that it's being found and loaded.
- If `$.connection.queue` is undefined, make sure you're loading the dynamic SignalR client (~/signalr/hubs).
- This line is wrong (if you're using 1.0.0-rc1):

`queue.ReloadQueueMember("Hello World!", "hi all");`

It should be:

`queue.client.reloadQueueMember("Hello World!", "hi all");`

- Similarly, this line would be wrong in 1.0.0-rc1:

`queue.send(name, 'hannan19')`

It should be:

`queue.server.send(name, 'hannan19')`

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I am using jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js. because I can not run my visual studio 2010 project after installing "jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.js" - after installing rc1.js I am getting an error like that "Version string specified for package reference 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR' is invalid."
can you please tell me what to do now??